# How do I pass the value of the token inside the Transformer?

Tags: php, laravel, transformer-model

I have a method where the user logs in, but I want to pass his token on the user transfomer, how to do?
I using Fractal.

before I used an ordinary json response, which would return the data plus the token.

// Authcontroller

public function authenticate(Request $request){

```
    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->response->errorUnauthorized('dados incorretos');
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return $this->response->withError('could_not_create_token', 500);
    }

    $user = getAuthUser();

    if (!$user->active) {
        return $this->response->errorUnauthorized('usuário não ativo');
    }
    $user = $user->token;

    // all good so return the token
    return $this->response->withItem($user, new UserTransformer());
}
```

//UserTransformer

```
public function transform(User $user)
{
    return [
        'id' => (int)$user->id,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'photo_url' => $user->photo_url,
        'active' => $user->active,
        'phone_number' => $user->phone_number,
        'company_id' => $user->company_id,
        'token' => $user->token,
     ];
}
```

Comment: @ceejayoz Did you read my doubt?

Comment: You asked how to pass additional data to the transformer. See the duplicate thread for how to do that.

Comment: TOKEN! just token my friend.

Comment: The token is a piece of data. Use the same technique from the duplicate thread. It works fine.